# Obtaining Result Based on Date Field of Another Column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, date

The below sql server 2005 query is currently working successfully. I need to modify the "p.Tx_Intent" to display based of a date column "p.Eff_DtTm" in the same table, so it only displays the latest Tx_Intent(Eff_DtTm) for the patient.

```
WITH T AS
( SELECT  s.Pat_Name, s.IDA, s.Pat_ID1, p.Tx_Intent, 
    ShortDesc = MAX(CASE WHEN s.SysDefStatus = 'SC' THEN s.Short_Desc END),
    Consult = MAX(CASE WHEN s.Activity = '123'
                        AND s.SysDefStatus = 'C' THEN s.App_DtTm END),
    SIM = MAX(CASE WHEN s.Activity = '456'
                          THEN s.App_DtTm END),
    PLANNING = MAX(CASE WHEN s.Activity = '789'
                          THEN s.App_DtTm END),
    TreatmentStart = MAX(CASE WHEN s.SysDefStatus = 'SC' THEN s.App_DtTm END),
    TreatmentFinished = MAX(CASE WHEN s.SysDefStatus = 'FC' THEN s.App_DtTm END)
FROM    vw_Schedule s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PatCPlan p
ON s.Pat_ID1=p.Pat_ID1 
WHERE   s.Activity IN ('123', '456', '789')
OR      s.SysDefStatus IN ('SC', 'FC', 'C')

GROUP BY s.Pat_Name, s.IDA, s.Pat_ID1, p.Tx_Intent

)


SELECT  Pat_Name,
 IDA,
    Tx_Intent,
    ShortDesc,
    Consult,
    Days = (DATEDIFF(dd, Consult, SIM)+1)-(DATEDIFF(wk, Consult, SIM)*2),
    SIM,
    Days = (DATEDIFF(dd, SIM, PLANNING)+1)-(DATEDIFF(wk, SIM, PLANNING)*2),
    PLANNING,
    Days = (DATEDIFF(dd, PLANNING, TreatmentStart)+1)-(DATEDIFF(wk, PLANNING, TreatmentStart)*2),
    TreatmentStart,
    Days = (DATEDIFF(dd, TreatmentStart, TreatmentFinished)+1)-(DATEDIFF(wk, TreatmentStart, TreatmentFinished)*2),
    TreatmentFinished
FROM    T;
```

Ok so i figured out a way to determine the most recent date im just having issues combinding it with my current query. Here is the query i need combined with the top query

```
   SELECT Pat_ID1, Tx_Intent from (select
       Pat_ID1
      ,Tx_Intent
      ,Eff_DtTm
      ,row_number() over (partition by Pat_ID1 order by abs(datediff(dd, Eff_DtTm,     getdate()))) Ranking
     from PatCPlan) xx
 where Ranking = 1
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Your original query probably did not emerge all at once but was growing little by little. If I were you, I'd take the same approach using the query you've found as a basis and building the new query around it. If you insist on keeping the old query and just "interweaving" the new one into it somehow, try to understand how it works, that should help (assuming you know very well how your present query works).

Comment: I seem to only be able to get it to display 1 result at a time :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure but here goes:

```
WITH PatCPlanRanked AS (
  SELECT
    Pat_ID1,
    Tx_Intent,
    Ranking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Pat_ID1 ORDER BY Eff_DtTm DESC)
  FROM PatCPlan
),
T AS
( SELECT  s.Pat_Name, s.IDA, s.Pat_ID1, p.Tx_Intent, 
    ShortDesc = MAX(CASE WHEN s.SysDefStatus = 'SC' THEN s.Short_Desc END),
    Consult = MAX(CASE WHEN s.Activity = '123'
                        AND s.SysDefStatus = 'C' THEN s.App_DtTm END),
    SIM = MAX(CASE WHEN s.Activity = '456'
                          THEN s.App_DtTm END),
    PLANNING = MAX(CASE WHEN s.Activity = '789'
                          THEN s.App_DtTm END),
    TreatmentStart = MAX(CASE WHEN s.SysDefStatus = 'SC' THEN s.App_DtTm END),
    TreatmentFinished = MAX(CASE WHEN s.SysDefStatus = 'FC' THEN s.App_DtTm END)
FROM    vw_Schedule s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PatCPlanRanked p
ON s.Pat_ID1=p.Pat_ID1 AND p.Ranking = 1
WHERE   s.Activity IN ('123', '456', '789')
OR      s.SysDefStatus IN ('SC', 'FC', 'C')

GROUP BY s.Pat_Name, s.IDA, s.Pat_ID1, p.Tx_Intent

)


SELECT  Pat_Name,
 IDA,
    Tx_Intent,
    ShortDesc,
    Consult,
    Days = (DATEDIFF(dd, Consult, SIM)+1)-(DATEDIFF(wk, Consult, SIM)*2),
    SIM,
    Days = (DATEDIFF(dd, SIM, PLANNING)+1)-(DATEDIFF(wk, SIM, PLANNING)*2),
    PLANNING,
    Days = (DATEDIFF(dd, PLANNING, TreatmentStart)+1)-(DATEDIFF(wk, PLANNING, TreatmentStart)*2),
    TreatmentStart,
    Days = (DATEDIFF(dd, TreatmentStart, TreatmentFinished)+1)-(DATEDIFF(wk, TreatmentStart, TreatmentFinished)*2),
    TreatmentFinished
FROM    T;
```

I made one change to your `Ranking` expression: in the OVER clause of the ROW_NUMBER function, I changed the

```
ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(dd, Eff_DtTm, GETDATE()))
```

to the more [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)

```
ORDER BY Eff_DtTm DESC
```

That is equivalent to your version *only if* `Eff_DtTm` can never be later than `GETDATE()`. But I assumed that to be the case because you expressed your intention as (*emphasis added*)

> so it only displays the **latest** Tx_Intent(Eff_DtTm) for the patient

and your expression can match that intention only under the above mentioned assumption.